# Getting Invalid syntax on a correct line of syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am getting an invalid syntax error when I run this code, but when i checked the line of the error, it seems to be correct. This is a code meant to calculate parts of parabolas.

```
def PCalculator():
    print("What are you missing?")
    print("D for directrix")
    print("F for focus")
    print("V for vertex")
    inp = input("Answer D, V, or F: ").lower()
    if inp == "v":
        fx = input("What is the X value of the focus? ")
        fy = input("What is the Y value of the focus? ")
        d = input("What is the Y value of the directrix? ")
        ptlst = [fx, fy, d]
        stopper = 1
        for x in ptlst:
            if (x.strip("-")).isnumeric() == False:
                stopper = 0
        if stopper == 1:
            fx = int(fx)
            fy = int(fy)
            d = int(d)
            vy = fy - ((abs(fy - d)/2)
            print("The vertex is (" + str(fx) + ", " + str(vy) + ")")  #this is where I am having the error
    elif inp == "f":
        vx = input("What is the X value of the vertex? ")
        vy = input("What is the Y value of the vertex? ")
        d = input("What is the Y value of the directrix? ")
        ptlst = [vx, vy, d]
        stopper = 1
        for x in ptlst:
            if (x.strip("-")).isnumeric() == False:
                stopper = 0
        if stopper == 1:
            vx = int(vx)
            vy = int(vy)
            d = int(d)
            fy = vy + (abs(vy - d))
            print("The focus is (" + str(vx) + "," + str(fy) + ")")
    else:
        print("ERROR: Letter detected")
PCalculator()
```

Comment: what line is the error being given on?

Comment: check the line above line number given in the error - that's often where the actual error is

Comment: Here's a reminder that syntax errors are usually on the previous line :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra opening bracket on this line:

```
vy = fy - ((abs(fy - d)/2)
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't see that. I didn't know that syntax errors sometimes point to the line below the error.